# Discord.py if statements not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have this code (Python 3.6), and its supposed to do, if the user has a wallet with them, then show the balance. If they don't have a wallet, crate a wallet and show the balance.

I have a file called amounts.json with the users id.

The code always jumps to the statement where it says the user does not have a account, when in fact I do, and gives me the error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: BlockIoAPIError: Failed: Label already exists on your account for Network=DOGE.
```

How can I fix it so it does not try and make a wallet every single time I do the balance command?

Code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def balance(ctx):
    user_id = ctx.message.author.id
    global amounts
    if user_id not in amounts:
        block_io.get_new_address(label=user_id)
        knee = block_io.get_address_balance(label=user_id)
        s1 = json.dumps(knee)
        d2 = json.loads(s1)
        d2['data']['available_balance']
        embed=discord.Embed(description="Bitcoin: btc here \n\nLitecoin: here\n\nDogecoin: {}".format(d2['data']['available_balance']), color=0x00ff00)
        await client.say(embed=embed)
        with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
            json.dump(amounts, f)
    elif user_id in amounts:
        knee = block_io.get_address_balance(label=user_id)
        s1 = json.dumps(knee)
        d2 = json.loads(s1)
        d2['data']['available_balance']
        embed=discord.Embed(description="Bitcoin: btc here \n\nLitecoin: here\n\nDogecoin: {}".format(d2['data']['available_balance']), color=0x00ff00)
        await client.say(embed=embed)
        with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
            json.dump(amounts, f)
```

Json code:

```
amounts = {}
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global amounts
    try:
        with open('amounts.json') as f:
            amounts = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load amounts.json")
        amounts = {}
```

Comment: Show the code where you load the `amounts.json` into the `amounts` variable.  Also, what is `block_io`?  That is where your error is.

Comment: block_io is a blockchain wallet thing @PatrickHaugh Ill update it with json code stuff now

Comment: Could you also show an entry from the amounts.json file?  Also check `print(discord.__version__)` to see which version of discord.py you're using.  In some versions `id`s are strings, but in more recent versions they are integers.

Comment: Version is 0.16.12

Comment: Entry would be:

Comment: {"354958338481586177": 0}

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Here :)

Comment: So is `amounts` a dictionary, or a list of dictionaries?

Comment: No idea. Not sure.

Comment: @Zatbot check the contents of your json file if you're not sure

Comment: So if your `amounts.json` has a `[{}, {}, {}, ...]` structure, that means that `user_id not in amounts` is always true, because user_id is not a dictionary.

Comment: Ohhh. How would I fix that? @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 0):

You need to datafix your json file so it has the structure your code expects.  If there are duplicate entries the below will sum their values.  This isn't part of your bot and you should only have to run this once.  You'll also want to go over any other code that touches or relies on `amounts`

```
import json

with open('amounts.json') as f:
    old_amounts = json.load(f)

new_amounts = {}
for d in old_amounts:
    for k, v in d:
        new_amounts[k] = new_amounts.get(k, 0) + v

with open('amounts.json') as f:
    json.dump(new_amounts, f)
```

Those `d2 = json.loads(s1)` lines should probably be `d2 = json.load(s1)`

Comment: Thanks a ton! Will test it soon :D

Comment: But if I did like: if user_id in x: would it be old amounts or new amounts going in that place?

Comment: After running this script, the `amounts.json` file should be changed to a dictionary structure, so when you `load` it into your bot you get a dictionary. So the next time you run your bot it will use the new amounts.