# Discord.py if statements/json not working

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

So, I made a post about this earlier today, and I followed [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51405534/6779307), and it still does not work.

I have a file called amounts.json with the users id.

The code always jumps to the statement where it says the user does not have a account, when in fact I do.

Its with the balance command, it works for the first time, then stops working and tells me a address already exists which means its using the same if statement over and over, creating a account over and over.

I followed one of the answers, and now json is not being written to at all..

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    with open('amounts.json') as f:
        old_amounts = json.loads(f)

    new_amounts = {}
    for d in old_amounts:
        for k, v in d:
            amounts[k] = amounts.get(k, 0) + v

    with open('amounts.json') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def balance(ctx):
    user_id = ctx.message.author.id
    global amounts
    if user_id not in amounts:
        block_io.get_new_address(label=user_id)
        knee = block_io.get_address_balance(label=user_id)
        s1 = json.dumps(knee)
        d2 = json.loads(s1)
        d2['data']['available_balance']
        embed=discord.Embed(description="Bitcoin: btc here \n\nLitecoin: here\n\nDogecoin: {}".format(d2['data']['available_balance']), color=0x00ff00)
        await client.say(embed=embed)
        with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
            json.dump(amounts, f)
    elif user_id in amounts:
        knee = block_io.get_address_balance(label=user_id)
        s1 = json.dumps(knee)
        d2 = json.loads(s1)
        d2['data']['available_balance']
        embed=discord.Embed(description="Bitcoin: btc here \n\nLitecoin: here\n\nDogecoin: {}".format(d2['data']['available_balance']), color=0x00ff00)
        await client.say(embed=embed)
        with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
            json.dump(amounts
```

EDIT:

Issue still not solved.

Comment: Is your bot throwing exceptions?  When I wrote that other answer I said "This isn't part of your bot and you should only have to run this once".  Why is the code from that answer in your `on_ready` event?

Comment: Where should I be running it? @PatrickHaugh

Comment: Just as a separate python script.  It should just transform the json from a list of dictionaries to a single dictionary.  That only needs to happen once.  You should open your `amounts.json` file in a text editor and check its structure. Then compare that with the structure that you expected it to be in when you wrote your bot.  Where did `amounts.json` come from?

Comment: Sorry. Im very confused. How would I run it in a different script? Any chance you can give a answer showing everything how it should be? @PatrickHaugh

Comment: You would take that text, put it in a file called, for example, `datafix.py` and then run `python3 datafix.py`.

Comment: How do I link them?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Im very confused, Im not sure what my code should look like. @PatrickHaugh

Comment: Im sorry @PatrickHaugh I have to go now, can you please leave a answer with what the code should be in what file and all that? Thank you so much

Comment: Your code shouldn't change at all.  You are seeing the problem because you wrote your code expecting `amounts.json` to contain a dictionary, but it contains a list of dictionaries. The best fix for that is to change `amounts.json`.  Since that only needs to happen once, I wrote a python script to do it.  That script is not supposed to replace any part of your bot.  You run it once in the bots directory, where it can see `amounts.json`.  It then reads that file and overwrites it with the same data in a different structure.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Sorry, it is kind of hard to understand you, can you please put a answer with everything I should do?